# Prevent certain attributes to be inherited in child class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Need some help to solve this puzzle folks:

When creating a child class in Python and defining the init method, I would like to import all the attributes of the super/parent class except certain positional parameters and
certain parameters (which are not defined inside parent classes' init method's list of positional or keyworded/non-keworded parameters but) defined within/inside the parent class init method with a default value.

Is there a way to prevent/avoid certain/specific parent class attributes to be imported in the child class upon initiation? I am aware that we can override methods in the child class which do not mimic parent class behaviors, but I am not aware how to do the same with attributes, so I was thinking if I could avoid them completely!

I will give an example of why I need a certain child class to mimic everything from its parent except certain attribute.

Consider a parent class "Car". The child class will be "ElectricCar". The parent class has an attribute defined called "liters_gasoline" with certain integer as  its default value.

Now, I would like to inherit everything in the ElectricCar sub-class except that "liters_gasoline" parameter, because ElectricCars don't use fuel/gasoline. How to prevent this "liters_gasoline" parameter from being inherited in the child class? I don't want this parameter in child class!

How to do this?

Comment: This sounds like an illogical use of inheritance. If ```Car``` is to be inherited by ```ElectricCar``` then the gasoline-related components should not be in ```Car```. A ```GasolineCar``` object can inherit ```Car``` and then define the gasoline-related attributes.

Comment: thank you brother. It makes total sense. I thought that I could have applied method_override type of concept to attributes_override too... that isn't doable with parent child classes it seems. So I should move away the gosoline related attributes away from the car. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something inherits from a parent class it should have all the attributes of the parent class. For example "liters_gasoline" should only be in the class of a gasoline car not an electric car.

Answer (score 2):

You are violating at least 2 principles there:

**1. [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) - [fat interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_bloat)**

If you decide to define `liters_gasoline` within the base class `Car`, remember that:

> no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.

Your plan is basically an example on how to contradict this rule. You are designing a fat interface, where your base class `Car` requires you to have the `liters_gasoline` and then later on, your subclass `ElectricCar` doesn't need it as it shouldn't be part of its characteristics.

> when an interface incorporates too many operations on some data into
> an interface, only to find that most of the objects cannot perform the
> given operations.

In analogy, I believe one of the more commonly known examples of this is designing a base class `Bird` with the functionality of `fly` which of course works for a subclass `Eagle` but not for a subclass `Penguin`.

**2. [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)**

If you decide to delete `liters_gasoline` within the subclass `ElectricCar`, remember that:

> if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with
> objects of type S (i.e., an object of type T may be substituted with
> any object of a subtype S) **without altering any of the desirable**
> **properties of the program**

Since you deleted the property `liters_gasoline` of S (`ElectricCar`), are you confident that it could still replace all objects of type T (`Car`). The answer is **no**. Why?

Let's say I'm performing the following:

```
print(T.liters_gasoline)
```

And I substitute S to that T:

```
print(S.liters_gasoline)  # Error, attribute doesn't exist.
```

Which means that your subtype S (`ElectricCar`) can't anymore be substituted to all types of T (`Car`).

### Solution

As @joey mentioned, redesign your interface (base class `Car`) to only include properties that are common for all types of `Car`.

Should there be any unavoidable instances where your subclass doesn't need a particular attribute of the base class (most of the time is a clue that you have a fat interface), you can choose to just nullify its value e.g. `self.some_attr_in_base = None` if you think a redesign wouldn't be necessary.

- Some may view this as an anti-pattern, but sometimes it is all that is needed. Even [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) supports this stating "*Fields inherited from abstract base classes can be overridden with another field or value, or be removed with None.*"

---

Related references:

- [Python: deleting a class attribute in a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057130/python-deleting-a-class-attribute-in-a-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions that I found is.. like I don't know it is accurate or not.. but it works. eg. you have

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, height):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

class Dog(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, color, owner):
        super().__init__(name, age, 0)
        self.color = color
        self.owner = owner
```

Answer (score 0):

If something inherits from a parent class it should have all the attributes of the parent class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).