# Delete an attribute of a parent class in a child class

Tags: python, oop, subclass

How i can delete attribute of parent class in child class (not class instanse) in subclassing?

```
class Parent:
    attribute1 = 1
    attribute2 = 2


class Child(Parent):
    # need only attribute1


try:
    print(Child.attribute2)
except AttributeError:
    print("You deleted class attribute2")
```

How can I implement this?

I tried to use delattr(Child, "attribute2") or this method in child class:

```
    def __delattr__(self, item):
        object.__delattr__(self, item)
```

But this doesn't work. Maybe i need to use super() inside child class?

Comment: `del Parent.attribute`??? It isn't clear to me precisely what the problem is.

Comment: Your `try, except` could be wrong. But maybe not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: deleting a class attribute in a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057130/python-deleting-a-class-attribute-in-a-subclass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I confused you.
I solved my problem in this way below, without attribute deleting.

```
class GrandParent:
    attribute1 = 1


class Parent(GrandParent):
    attribute2 = 2


class Child(GrandParent):
    # need only attribute1
    pass
```